React app fetch request from IP address if no domain name is available
I have written a React application (React+Vite) which makes some fetch requests.
Here is an example:
const fetchRows = async () => {
  let rows = [];
  const response = await axios.post(
    'http://localhost:81/api/get_rows',
    {}
  );
  rows.push(response.data['rows']);
  return rows;
};

It doesn't matter too much what this code does. The important part is the hostname used in the request, in this case the POST request is directed to localhost:81.
This works fine during development where the same machine is used to host the backend webserver, the NodeJS/React/Vite development environment/server and the web browser use to test the whole system.
Unsurprisingly, this no longer works in production, when my application and backend logic is deployed to a server on the cloud, and I am trying to interact with it from some other machine.
I do not have a domain name setup for this system. I can create one if absolutly necessary, however I would prefer to just hardcode the ip address in place of localhost rather than go and buy a domain name.

I know that domain names are not expensive, I just don't want to configure it as this is for a demonstration project and it doesn't have any particularly important application other than as a demo.

Is there a relatively easy way to write some React code which uses an ip address in place of localhost without resorting to hardcoding the address which obviously isn't a great solution?
eg: Is there a React or JavaScript function which can ask the host machine what its ip address is?
This might not be so easy since any machine has multiple ip addresses. (127.0.0.1 being an obvious example that all Linux hosts have.)
Any suggestions welcome. If buying a domain is easier, I'll just do that.

setting up hosting for a frontend app is different than setting up hosting for an API... What kind of api is api/get_rows? If it's static data you could just host json files, in your assets folder, but then you could easily include the data in you app instead.

@user3791775 To clarify - there's a Python backend which hosts this API, then there's a static site built using React/Vite as the frontend. The html/js/css generated by Vite is being hosted by nginx on some cloud server, as is the Python backend API (although this runs on a different port number, 81 instead of 80).

As your API routes seem to start with /api anyway, I'd suggest setting up nginx so it routes those requests to your backend. Then you can simply omit the host in the URL.

@CherryDT That sounds like something that I don't know how to do, and I don't understand how that would work either. Can you offer any advice? I'm a bit confused since the code (HTML+JS) for the website front end is static, how would nginx be able to change which ip address is sent to a browser making a request to the frontend?

There wouldn't be a need for any. The request would be just to /api/get_rows without host. nginx would serve everything except /api/* from static files and for /api/* it would act as reverse proxy for the backend on the other port.

@CherryDT Unless I misunderstand, the browser on a remote machine will make this request, so how would that work?

The browser of course knows what page it currently loaded.

@CherryDT yes but unless the JS it receives contains the correct IP of the backend, it is just going to call axios.post(localhost)

No it calls the page it is on (for example, if I'd do axios.get('/questions') on this page it would end up fetching from https://stackoverflow.com/questions). And that's fine if that page is served by nginx and nginx also proxies /api/* requests to the backend.

@CherryDT Ah - I'm using axios incorrectly. I'm using the full address. But I thought I needed that since the backend is served on a different port number?

True but that's why my suggestion was to configure nginx in such a way that it acts as reverse proxy for /api/* routes to your backend. So you wouldn't call your backend directly, it would be routed through nginx to your backend. From the outside it would then all be under the same domain/IP and port (served by nginx).

@CherryDT That makes sense. I'll do that

Add to your config (within the server block) location /api { proxy_pass http://your-server.com:81; } with your IP instead of your-server.com (google nginx api proxy for more examples)

@CherryDT proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/api; <- what I used in the end
